# taking someone's destiny data and puting it on your account

Tags: destiny

I already have a destiny character on my destiny game, but I was wondering if I take my brother destiny data and put it on my ps4 account will I have my character and his character.

Comment: I'm only speculating, but I would imagine the character data is locked to the PSN user.

Answer (score 7):

No.

Characters are stored on the Destiny servers and linked to the appropriate online account (PSN or Xbox Live depending on your platform).

You can not "copy" character data to duplicate characters between accounts.